# More control over priority-job-queue

Tags: android, multithreading, android-priority-jobqueue

So, I have implemented `priority-job-queue` which is perfectly documented and meets all my requirements. I have some difficulties though. As per client's request, I had to divide networks call into two parts, offline (queued server calls with `priority-job-queue`) and run-time (instant server calls). To cut short, what I'm trying to accomplish is to execute all queued server-calls before instant-run call (which is independent of `priority-job-queue`) being executed. Is there any way to handle this case. I would appreciate any help.

> NOTE: I know a method called `JobManager.count()`, but after reading
>   this post
>   (https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue/issues/193), I got
>   confused a little bit if it really returns count of pending jobs or
>   not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just give those instant calls a higher priority and run them using priority-job-queue as well?

Comment: I believe I'll go with that. And I got stuck again. So what I want is to put failed server-request to `shouldReRunOnThrowable()` block and `stop()` JobManager there. So failed request will be fired when JobManager `start()`s. Well, I see structure feels cumbersome. But, we really need it. P.S. what happens if I `stop()` JobManager inside `shouldReRunOnThrowable` block and then `return RetryConstraint.RET RY`. Will this call be still retried when JobManager `start()`s. Because in normal case, any job after `stop()` not added to queue until JobManager `start()`s.